# How to resize window using WinAPI

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, resize

I'm want to resize a window using WinAPI. I use a WinAPI function:

```
SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
```

The window is resized, but its content is not redrawn. If I resize this window using the mouse, the content redraws. How to resize window using WinAPI with content redrawing?

Comment: Are you really using C#?  If so, why are you trying to use P/Invoke to accomplish this?  The managed API will take care of all of this for you.

Comment: Use the Form.Size property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25w4thew.aspx

Comment: No. I resize window of another program, not my.

Comment: Control.FromHandle works only for the current process. It returns null if you pass it a handle that belongs to an other process.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you don't specify `SWP_NOREDRAW` in the `uFlags` parameter. If it's not set and the window still doesn't redraw, call [`UpdateWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatewindow) after calling `SetWindowPos`.

Answer (score 2):

By default the window is not redrawn (more precisely - not invalidated) upon resize. If you shrink the window - it won't receive the `WM_PAINT` message at all. And if you enlarge it - the update region will only include the added area.

If the contents of the window depend on its size - the window **itself** must decide to invalidate itself (via a call to `InvalidateRect`/`InvalidateRgn`) upon processing `WM_SIZE` message.

Nevertheless you can invalidate any window at any time by calling `InvalidateRect`/`InvalidateRgn`.

Comment: You may call InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE); This should redraw the window (asynchronously)

Comment: I test this, no effect. Which message sends to window when them resizing by mouse?

Comment: Well, this should help IMHO, I can't imagine why this doesn't work without seeing what really happens there.

In order to cause a window redraw itself all you have to do is call InvalidateRect/InvalidateRgn. After calling one of those functions you may call UpdateWindow so that the target window will repaint itself immediately (otherwise the painting may be postponed until the message queue of the target thread becomes idle).

Answer (score 2):

Write this code in window procedure:

Code:

```
case WM_SIZE:
    {
        HWND groupControl;
        RECT rcClient;//screen size

        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcClient);

        groupControl = GetDlgItem(hwnd,Id);//get the id of control
        SetWindowPos(groupControl, NULL, rcClient.right-50, 
         rcClient.bottom-50, 20, 20,
          SWP_NOZORDER);//set a coordinate of control and 
       height and width.
    }
```